# Base class for Enums

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums

I have the following predicament:

I have several enum types:

```
Enum1
Enum2
...
```

I have a generic class implementation

```
GenericClass<T> where T : struct and all the other interfaces :)
```

And finally a class that contains a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Type, GenericClass<{some enum base type}>
```

On this class's constructor I do something like this:

```
dictionary.Add(typeof(Enum1), new GenericClass<Enum1>());
dictionary.Add(typeof(Enum2), new GenericClass<Enum2>());
```

The problem is, I can't figure out **IF** I can express the {some enum base type} so that the instructions in the constructor could work.

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need any more info.

**edit:**

Thanks to nvoigt's answer I've finally reached the following solution:

First, for a bit of context, the GenericClass has two methods relevant to this thread:

```
public void SetValue(T key, int value)
public int GetValue(T Key)
```

I've made the GenricClass implement an empty interface. Now the class that references the generic class looks something like this:

```
private Dictionary<Type, IGenericRequirementsCollection> _requirements;

public RequirementsCollection()
{
    _requirements = new Dictionary<Type, IGenericRequirementsCollection>();

    _requirements.Add(typeof(Enum1), new GenericRequirementsCollection<Enum1>());
    _requirements.Add(typeof(Enum2), new GenericRequirementsCollection<Enum2>());
    ...
}

public int GetValue<T>(T key) where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    if (!_requirements.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) throw new ArgumentException();

    return (_requirements[typeof(T)] as GenericRequirementsCollection<T>).GetValue(key);
}

public void SetValue<T>(T key, int value) where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    if (!_requirements.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) throw new ArgumentException();

    (_requirements[typeof(T)] as GenericRequirementsCollection<T>).SetValue(key, value);
}
```

This is just a head-up, for other people potentially stuck with this problem, in order to have a complete answer.

Comment: If it makes any sense in the application you could also make `GenericClass<T>` inherit from a non-generic and use that base class as the `TValue` of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your generic class has a common non-generic interface, you could use that interface. Otherwise, you need to resort to store it as object and cast the result using the type you stored as key.

Comment: Talk about not seeing the forest for the trees. Thank you, the non generic interface trick worked. Thank you very much!